# How do you add alternative text to images in Dokuwiki?

Tags: syntax, alt, dokuwiki

This is my image syntax...

[{{ :image-link.png?200|This is the caption.}}]

Which adds the image, right aligned.

Your help is greatly appreciated... Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

The DokuWiki syntax you quote shows you are using the [Image box plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:imagebox)  - which allows a caption, but produces a blank *alt* tag.

e.g. `[{{ :software:contao:contao_install_open_sauce_00.png |Layout -> Themes -> Themes Import}}]`

renders the HTML:- `<div class="thumb2 tcenter" style="width:100%"><div class="thumbinner"><a href="/business/lib/exe/detail.php?id=software%3Acontao%3Acontao_4&amp;media=software:contao:contao_install_open_sauce_00.png" class="media" title="software:contao:contao_install_open_sauce_00.png"><img exify_intitialized="true" src="/business/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=software:contao:contao_install_open_sauce_00.png" class="mediabox2" alt=""></a><div class="thumbcaption"><strong>Layout </strong>→<strong> Themes </strong>→<strong> Themes Import</strong></div></div></div>`

and creates an [boxed image with a caption](https://scottferguson.com.au/uploads/files/imagebox_plugin.png) (Wikipedia style) and an empty *alt* tag.

So you can **not** populate an *alt* field using the Imagebox plugin, but you can populate an *alt* field using the [built-in image tag] [3]. The *alt* tag generated by the built-in image tag is populated by the value you give to the (tooltip) "caption".

e.g. `{{ wiki:dokuwiki-128.png |This is the caption}}` (see :wiki:syntax#media_files)

renders the HTML `<a href="/_detail/wiki:dokuwiki-128.png?id=wiki%3Asyntax" class="media" title="wiki:dokuwiki-128.png"><img exify_intitialized="true" src="/_media/wiki:dokuwiki-128.png" class="mediacenter" title="This is the caption" alt="This is the caption"></a>`

If you want to use both a *title* tag (tooltip) and a different *alt* tag you need to enable HTML in your DokuWiki and add the image using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What you did should already succeed in providing the image with an alt text (not with a caption!), except that you don't need the external square brakets:

```
{{ :image-link.png?200|This is the alt-text.}}
```

If you want a caption instead, you should look at some plugin such as [the box plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:box).

Finally, if you wanted a *link* consisting in an image with an alt-text, just use something like

```
[[www.theaddress.it|{{ :image-link.png?200|This is the alt-text.}}]]
```